# Javascript make arrays equal length with unknown data and unknown amount of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object like so..

```
 data = [
// I'll never know how many objects are here, but the name will always be unique.
   {
    "name": "Junior",
    "data": [
 // I'll never know how many entries are here, but the first index will always be a date string and the value is the second index
      ["2021-01-02", 4],
      ["2021-01-06", 1],
      ["2021-01-08", 1]
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Adult",
    "data": [
      ["2021-01-02", 6],
      ["2021-01-05", 1],
      ["2021-01-06", 9],
      ["2021-01-07", 1],
     ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Playing",
    "data": [
      ["2021-01-06", 1]
    ]
  }
]
```

What I need to do is make sure that each data property is the same, so if there is a missing date in one property, it should get added to the others with a 0 value, the expected outcome would be below;

```
.. {
    name: "Junior"
    data: [
       ["2021-01-02", 4],
       ["2021-01-05", 0],
       ["2021-01-06", 1],
       ["2021-01-07", 0],
       ["2021-01-08", 1]
     ]
  },
{
   "name": "Adult",
   "data": [
     ["2021-01-02", 6],
     ["2021-01-05", 1],
     ["2021-01-06", 9],
     ["2021-01-07", 1],
     ["2021-01-08", 0]
   ]
 },
   {
     "name": "Playing",
     "data": [
        ["2021-01-02", 0],
        ["2021-01-05", 0],
        ["2021-01-06", 1],
        ["2021-01-07", 0],
        ["2021-01-08", 0]
      ]
    }
```

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: do you want a new array? have you tried anything? what does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can first get `Set` of unique months and then apply `map` on the actual data:

```js
const data = [ { "name": "Junior", "data": [ ["2021-01-02", 4], ["2021-01-06", 1], ["2021-01-08", 1] ] }, { "name": "Adult", "data": [ ["2021-01-02", 6], ["2021-01-05", 1], ["2021-01-06", 9], ["2021-01-07", 1], ] }, { "name": "Playing", "data": [ ["2021-01-06", 1] ] }];

const allMonth = [...new Set(data.flatMap(o=>o.data.map(([date])=>date)))];

const result = data.map(o=>({...o, data:allMonth.map(i=>[i, Object.fromEntries(o.data)[i] || 0])}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the parentheses in the last line: `data.map(o=> ({...}) <--these here )`

Comment: @Petyor This is spread operator. You can read it more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: I meant the parentheses not the spread operator. I am not familiar with this syntax: `({})` and what it does

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the data in an object with date and name as keys and map new objects.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "Junior", data: [["2021-01-02", 4], ["2021-01-06", 1], ["2021-01-08", 1]] }, { name: "Adult", data: [["2021-01-02", 6], ["2021-01-05", 1], ["2021-01-06", 9], ["2021-01-07", 1]] }, { name: "Playing", data: [["2021-01-06", 1]] }],
    temp = data.reduce((r, { name, data }) => {
        data.forEach(([date, value]) => (r[date] ??= {})[name] = value);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    dates = Object.keys(temp).sort(),
    result = data.map(({ name }) => ({ name, data: dates.map(date => [date, temp[date][name] || 0]) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```